# how do you jQuery load() into dynamically created element when using asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I’m unable to load plain HTML into a dynamically created DIV element. My script looks as follows:

```
$("button").click(function () {
  var divElem = $('&lt;div /&gt;').load('@Url.Action("MyFunkyPartialView", "Home")');
});
```

MyFunkyPartialView action method returns a partial view that looks as follows:

Comment: `.load()` loads the data into the selected element. `$('')` selects nothing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where does your newly created `DIV` element go?

When you create an HTML element (i.e. `$('<div/>')`), that's not automatically inserted into the document, so you can't see it on the screen yet. You'll have to specify where you want to put it.

It is, however, already in memory, so you can already manipulate it and do stuff to it, including adding content to it as you're doing. Nothing wrong with your call to `.load()`.

Long story short then, is that you're doing nothing wrong --- you're just missing a step in your workflow.

The only thing you have to do, then, is to insert the `DIV` to your document. You can do that using something like:

```
var divElem = $('<div/>').load('@Url.Action("MyFunkyPartialView", "Home")');
// ...
divElem.appendTo('#main');
```

This adds the `DIV` element inside the `#main` element, after all it's original content.

#### EDIT

When accessing the `DIV`'s contents, we have to make sure that the `.load()` call has had a chance to complete first. Normally this is best achieved through the `complete` callback.

```
var divElem = $('<div/>')
    .load('@Url.Action("MyFunkyPartialView", "Home")', function () {
        // this function executes after the load AJAX call completes,
        // so this is the best place to access the contents of the div.
        alert(divElem.html());
    });
```

Comment: Neil Ilagan -- The thing is I treat my divElem as a dummy placeholder from which I want to fetch .html() and afterwards divElem.remove(). Can this be done?

Comment: Hmm. You can, but I don't see the point though. You can slap the `.load()`ed HTML into your placeholder, and (correct) retrieve that using `.html()` and slap that onto another container/placeholder somewhere in your document. My question now, however, is why not just put the HTML into it's final resting place from the get-go? Why use a dynamic placeholder?

Comment: @Neil Ilagan -- When I do it your way, I append my dummy DIV to the BODY. In Firebug, I see the dummy DIV holds the downloaded HTML. But alert(divElem.html()) shows nothing. Why?

Comment: My point in the comment was, instead of doing something like `var x = $('<div/>').load(); $('#container').html(x.html()); x.remove()`, why not jump the gun and just do `$('#container').load()`? So there shouldn't be a dummy `div` per se. To answer your question though, that may be because you're accessing (`alert`ing) the `div` element before the AJAX call has had a chance to complete. Editing my answer to make that more apparent.

Comment: @Neil Ilagan -- If I set up a callback function for load(), and place alert(divElem.html()) in the body of the callback function, then it works. I still have a problem -- the divElem has to be glued in the document. If I don't append divElem to BODY, things don't work. I'm trying to accomplish something similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346361/how-do-you-jquery-load-into-dynamically-created-element-when-using-asp-net-mvc.

Comment: then why not append the `divElem` to the body, as my answer initially suggested? :)

Comment: @Neil Ilagan -- If you glue an element in the document, a user can see the element's contents on the screen. Therefore, I'd prefer massaging HTML in memory before I show the final product to the user.